# storing fractions with single precision float point variables

Tags: floating-point

I'm reading registers off a flow computer at work (kind of like a PLC). Per the documentation, the registers are stored as IEEE single precision floats. I read the registers and store them in CComVariants (wrapper of the MS VARIANT class).

I know values like this are stored on the device registers...

```
0.45
0.3
0.2
0.05
```

When I pause execution via a break-point in VS2010 I see values with wierd trailing fractions like this...

```
0.4500000000031
0.300000034
0.2000000005
0.05000000004
```

My question is, is this a problem with Visual Studio 2010 IDE being imprecise or are IEEE single precision floats simply not precise enough for this application (+/-0.00001)?

I ask because I may have to put in code to check to see if these values are in a certain range later on and code to check to see if all these fractions sum to 1.

Answer (score 1):

floating point precision is the number of places after the decimal point.
Single / double etc is the range of number it is capable of storing and how many places it's capable of keeping after the point.

If you want exact representations, then you can't use floating points.

You could try converting them to the decimal type, or some other type ( * 100 and use int for instance), or just take it as accurate enough and leave it.

A floating point is simply incapable of representing all the possible values it's range. There will be gaps. IT's the same sort of issue as writing in 1/3 in decimal.

0.33333333 is close, but it's a asymptotic. You can get closer to 1/3 by addinhg more 3s, but you'll never get there.

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point numbers do not store fractions generally. Typically, a single-precision floating-point number, a "float", stores a sign, a 24-bit binary numeral (the "significand"), and an eight-bit exponent by which to scale the numeral. If the sign is s (+1 or -1), the significand is f, and the exponent is e, then the stored float represents s * f * 2<sup>e</sup>.

A float cannot represent .45 exactly because there is no sign, significand, and exponent such that s * f * 2<sup>e</sup> is exactly .45. No amount of precision can change this, because there is no integer that, when multiplied by 2 raised to the power of an integer, exactly equals .45. Therefore, when .45 is prepared for storage in a float, it must be rounded, typically to the nearest number that a float can represent. This is why you see 0.4500000000031.

Note that there are some things I have left out. These probably will not help with your immediate problem, but I mention them for completeness:  There can be atypical floating-point representations. They are rare these days; they were more common before the IEEE-754 standard for floating-point arithmetic. Although the significand is 24 bits, only 23 are stored; the leading bit is implicitly one. The eight-bit exponent is stored as a number in the interval 1 to 254 representing exponents of -126 to 127.  When the stored exponent is 0, the significand has fewer than 24 bits; the implicit bit is zero, and the exponent remains clamped at -126. When the stored exponent is 255, the float represents infinity (if the significand is zero) or "not a number" (otherwise). The latest IEEE-754 standard specifies formats for decimal arithmetic, but not all systems support it.

If the system you use supports decimal arithmetic, and all the numbers you work with are exactly representable as decimals in the available precision, you could use that to get exact answers.

If you do not have decimal arithmetic, one choice is to use the more common binary floating-point arithmetic but deal with the rounding errors. Sometimes, when you have a list of numbers that add exactly to 1, and you store them in floats and sum the floats, you will get an answer that is not exactly 1. And sometimes, when you have numbers that do not add to 1, and you add them in the same way, you will get exactly 1. So there can be false positive results ("Yes, the sum is 1", but it is not) and false negative results ("No, the sum is not 1", but it is). You might choose to reject false negatives at the expense of accepting false positives.  (E.g., calculate how much error could occur in your summing process and accept any number that close to 1. This will cause you to accept all sums that would be 1 if done exactly, but it will also cause you to accept some sums that would not be 1 if done exactly.)

If that is not acceptable to you, there might be other ways to perform your computation. If all of your numbers have the form n/100, where n is an integer, then store n in an int instead of storing n/100 in a float. Then you can add the integers exactly, and, if the sum of the stored integers is 100, you know the exact sum is 1.